# Google bot system

Tags: python, python-requests

So. I'm confused.
I'm making SINGLE request using

```
 headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36',

}
    response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?num=1&q=Philippines Loans&oq=Philippines Loans&&start=10',headers=headers).text
```

However it wants me to fill in captcha. I make the same exact request at my browser; it works just fine no captcha. How come it doesn't work when I make a request through python? How is google detecting weather if I'm making request through a script or not? I'd understand if I was making 100 requests. But I'm only making one request and it still throws me error. Same request I make in my google chrome it works just fine. I thought it had to do with user-agent. Apparently not. What might be the case? What else should I pass? Isn't `requests.get` same as making a get request manually through google chrome? What makes it different? Previously before it had me fill in captcha I did make more than 500 requests with no sleep timer on it.

Comment: If you start anonymous session and make sure there are no cookies, will you still get a response through browser? BTW - until recently I could log into Google just by sending a proper payload. Now I have o parse login page. I bet they changed something in the Matrix.

Comment: Try using bing instead.

Comment: Normally google got query limit protection on single IP  requests(with different machines on same network). Play with caches not unique requests. **Google already work with caches !**

Comment: @dsgdfg So I'm assuming by different machines you mean one is chrome browser another one is python-requests?

Comment: Where your browser cookies ? Easy detect which request haven't any cookies . Anonymous and User are different , so go use google developer api, who give a service  with anonymously ? All service want collect user data (data mining) and how be saying *"we don't need user information data !"*

Comment: @dsgdfg  I've tried making a request by passing in cookie. No luck with that either.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted works for me.

Google will monitor your IP and traffic coming from it. If you're doing *inhuman* amounts of requests then google will blacklist your IP for some period and require you to solve a captcha. If you wait a few hours you should stop seeing the caption.

The only real way of getting around this is to use proxies, however you will find that most free proxies that you can find on the web are blacklisted by google already. So if you want a somewhat solid implementation you'd have to setup your own proxy server(s) with a provider that allows you to rotate IPs or, in lieu, rent dedicated proxy-servers. Those tend to be fairly pricey though.

Comment: That doesn't make sense as to why I can still make queries using the same IP using google chrome and don't have to fill in captcha? But have to fill in captcha using python_requests?

Comment: Remember that there is more to a request than just the User-Agent.
You have a multitude of different HTTP-Headers (other than just the User-Agent) that are set by your browser that python requests will not set for you by default. This includes cookies among other things.
Also keep in mind that chrome might be sending HTTP-Headers that it won't even tell you about in the dev-tools.